# How do I reset my WPF Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, mvvm, dependency-properties

So I created a UserControl, and I created a dependency property for it so I can use it for my animation.
The animation works, it sets off but when I click a new item it doesnt *slide* back in it jumps back to the start and then restarts.

How do I make the animation slide back in.
This is due to the true and false statements in the OnSelectionChanged.

```
<Grid.Resources>
            <system:Double x:Key="SlideOffSet">50</system:Double>
            <Storyboard x:Key="SlideRight">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                 From="0" To="{StaticResource SlideOffSet}"
                                 Duration="0:0:0.2" />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="SlideLeft">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                 From="{StaticResource SlideOffSet}" To="0"
                                 Duration="0:0:0.2" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>

<local:CustomizedList x:Name="uc" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding}" />

 <StackPanel Grid.Column="2"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="50"
                    Background="Gray">

            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideRight}" />
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideLeft}" />
                            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>

            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>

        </StackPanel>
```

UserControl

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="list" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="List_OnSelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="2" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Brown">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="1">
                            <TextBlock.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="AliceBlue"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Blue"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </TextBlock.Background>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And the SelectionChanged event for the Dependency Property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomizedList));

        public bool SelectedItem
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

        private void List_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedItem = false;
            SelectedItem = true;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you setting the SelecedItem to false and then to true immediately afterwards? The UI won't update in between.

Comment: @mm8 That was the only way I could think of to get it to change the value to false

Comment: So how and from where are you calling List_OnSelectionChanged?

Comment: @mm8 From the usercontrol, I added it to the question, my bad

Comment: I still don't understand the code in your event handler. It makes no sense to set the property to true *and* false.

Comment: @mm8 That's the only way I could think of to make it change it's value so it can atleast start over, if I bind it to move the stackpanel on true, when does it know when to slide back if I dont change it to false right after?

Comment: It should slide back whenever the SelectedItem property is set to false.

Comment: @mm8 Which it wont unless I explicitly set it to false after it's true.
When the selected item changed ti turns false to reset it's position then true to move again

Comment: I don't follow your logic. You can set the property to either true or false. Please always provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your example when asking a question.

Comment: That's what I did `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=uc, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="True">` as you can see, it triggers the animation when the value is true

Comment: Yes, and it should slide back when the property is set to false. But you are setting it to true in your event handler for some reason.

Comment: @mm8 Where else would it get the property value from? When the item is selected I want it to be true and when another item is selected, make it slide back and slide out again

Comment: Now I think I understand what you are trying to do. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the item is selected I want it to be true and when another item is selected, make it slide back and slide out again

Well, then you need to wait asynchronously for the animation to occur before you set the property back to `true`. Try this:

```
private async void List_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedItem = false;
    await Task.Delay(1000); //wait for a second
    SelectedItem = true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah like that but it feels like a bad patch if you know what I mean? You're getting it though, I'll accept this answer to stop bugging you and I'll keep reading docs, I'm sure you have better things to do, thanks for the help

Comment: If you want it to slide to the right and then back again in one go, this is what you will have to do. The UI thread cannot animate your transform and execute the event handler simultaneously.

Comment: Could I open a new question with a better example?

Comment: Well, yes, if you actually have a new question.

Comment: it would be the same question with a better example, I guess I could update this one

Comment: Don't edit the question if you have a new one. This question has already been anwered. Another example either is a new question or doesn't change the answer.

Comment: Created a new question if you wanna check it out